# Appending monad

Tags: haskell, monads

With just `putChar` I can do stuff like this:

```
f = 
  do
    putChar 'a'
    putChar 'b'
    g
    putChar 'f'
    putChar 'g'

g =
  do
    putChar 'c'
    putChar 'd'
    putChar 'e'
```

And what I will find when I "run" this (by saying `main = f`) it'll just print the characters out in order.

What I'm looking for is a non-`IO` version. Something that works a bit like this:

```
f = 
  do
    append 'a'
    append 'b'
    g
    append 'f'
    append 'g'

g =
  do
    append 'c'
    append 'd'
    append 'e'
```

And a function, say `runAppend :: t a -> [a]`

Such that `runAppend f` = `['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']`

Naturally I'd want this to run in linear time (i.e. not suffer issues like `++` does when you do the concatenations in a bad order).

This seems like a fairly common use case so I'm guessing it exists, if someone could point me to it that would be good, I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`Writer` monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer.html) for this:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.DList (DList)
import qualified Data.DList as DList

type Append c = Writer (DList c)

append :: c -> Append c ()
append = tell . pure

runAppend :: Append c () -> [c]
runAppend = DList.toList . execWriter

f, g :: Append Char ()
```

This is a bit more complicated than necessary because it uses a `DList Char` instead of a `String`. [`DList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.5) gives you an efficient `Monoid` instance for this case where you keep appending to the end.

Comment: Is `DList` necessary? `Control.Monad.Writer` has pretty [pure perfomance](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-March/019528.html), and with just `List` `runAppend $ do append xs; append ys; append zs` will desugar to `xs ++ ys ++ zs` and not to `(xs ++ ys) ++ zs`.

Comment: Well doesn't that depend on the shape of your real functions playing the parts of `f` and `g`?

Comment: Yes, taking `f` and `g` from the question, `g` will be traversed twice. I'm just not sure whether this optimization worth introducing possible syntactic overhead (`toList`, `fromList` — that stuff). I would use the strict `Writer` from the link I mentioned, if I would want to optimize.

Answer (score 9):

The [Writer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer.html) monad does this:

```
> let g = tell "b" >> tell "c" >> tell "d"
> runWriter (tell "a" >> g >> tell "e")
((),"abcde")
```